# Using PDO_MYSQL DSN and Adding Attributes to the Array

Tags: mysql, pdo, sql-injection

I'm trying to create a secure, SQL-injection proof connection to a database using PDO.  I've know certain character sets are vulnerable, but that UTF-8 is not one of them.  I also know that I should turn PDO's prepared statement emulation mode off.  Below is the code that I've put together for the connection.  My question is twofold.

1. Can someone please take a look at my code below to make sure that I'm doing everything correctly?  I've tested it, and it works. But is there something else I could add to make it more secure or am I doing it right?
2. I'm not 100% positive that my syntax for what's inside the array is correct, though I don't get any errors when I do an insert, so I'm inclined to believe that it is.  However, is there a way to test or confirm that those attributes are actually being set?  Or can someone tell by looking that the syntax is correct and those attributes are definitely being set?

Thanks for any help in advance.  My full code for the database connection and an insert using a prepared statement is below.

```
function addItem($category, $item, $price) {

   $dsn = 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=myDatabase;charset=utf8';
   $username = "myUsername";
   $password = "myPassword";
   $options = array(
      PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
      PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
   ); 

   try {

    $link = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);

    $query = $link->prepare("INSERT INTO items (category, item, price)
                                        VALUES (:category, :item, :price)");

    $query->bindParam(':category', $category);
    $query->bindParam(':item', $item);
    $query->bindParam(':price', $price); 

    $query->execute();

    echo "New item added successfully";
   }

   catch(PDOException $e)  {
     echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
   }

   $link = null;
 }
```

Comment: It’s the *mix* of certain character encodings that are prone to flaws.

Comment: You have setup the `$options` array correctly. If you want to verify it, you can check the output from `var_dump($link->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES))` You may also modify your `INSERT` statement to be invalid, and watch as PDO throws an exception caught in your `catch`.

Comment: All your code looks fine and secure. The one thing I'd change is make the `addItem()` function accept a parameter `$link` and establish the connection outside the function. The way you have it now, you're creating a new database connection for each insert, which can be highly inefficient and increase the risk of using up the server's available connections.  Instead, establish the connection once per script run and pass the variable `$link` into functions that need to use it.

Comment: I appreciate the comments, thank you very much.  @MichaelBerkowski, yes that makes a lot of sense to pass the $link parameter into the function.  I will definitely make that change in my code.  Thanks!